# Usernames and passwords with ÅÄÖ

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I am not sure what the problem depends on since I'm new to PHP. The snippet below checks if the username and the password match with the username and password in the database. The database has the `utf8_general_ci` and the script has `UTF-8` but when it checks if they match it doesn't recognize `ÅÄÖ`. Why is it like this? I've read a number of posts like this but I cannot find the solution.

**The snippet:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['loginBtn'])){
//variables 
$username = mb_strtolower($_POST['username']);
$password = $_POST['password'];

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
    $statusM = "Var god och fyll i båda fälten!";   
    }else{
        //$password = hash("sha512", $password);

        /*
        $options = array('cost' => 12);
        $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
        */


        include("db.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username COLLATE utf8_bin AND password=:password COLLATE utf8_bin";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        if(!$stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        $statusM = "Antingen fel lösenord eller användarnamn!"; 
        }else{

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username COLLATE utf8_bin AND password=:password COLLATE utf8_bin';
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);     
        $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['school'] = $row['school'];
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        header("Location: member_home.php");
        exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**NOTE** * The code is not done and the site is in swedish.

**The questions:**

1. Why can't I compare when the username or the password contain `ÅÄÖ`?
2. Where is the problem, in MYSQL or in PHP?

Comment: i would crypt password with something like Sha512. That would also solve your problem. Base64 could then also work for username because you can encode and decode with it

Comment: I've removed the password hashing here, but that is not the solution. But thanks!

Comment: Try `$db->set_charset("utf8");` just above any of your `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users...` @user3241442

Comment: Sorry, that didn't solve my problem. I've done charsets.

Comment: Set the charset on HTML with **<meta charset="UTF-8" />** and add a **header** with that: **header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');**. It cant work, if the database in UTF-8 but the site not.

Answer (score 0):

So, about the [mb_strtolower()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php), try to run this script, and see the difference:

```
$statusM = "Var god och fyll i båda fälten!"; 
echo mb_strtolower($statusM);
echo mb_strtolower($statusM, 'UTF-8');
```